# Touchable view and activating another components animation

Tags: react-native

New to react native and in a component, I have a list of views that include a checkbox (react-native-bouncy-checkbox). Each view is wrapped in a TouchableWithoutFeedback(So I can click the entire view, not just the checkbox) and I have a boolean useState to tell the checkbox whether to display the check or not.

The issue I'm at is that I chose the library for the checkbox because the animation when it's clicked looks very nice. However, the animation doesn't play if I hit the view ~ only if I hit the actual checkbox, which is rather small in my app.

Is there any way to tell another component that it needs to act like it was pressed, so it can play its animation?

Code for clarity:

```
const Task = ({ id, text }: Types) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setChecked(!checked)}>
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <BouncyCheckbox
                    disableBuiltInState={true}
                    isChecked={checked}
                    fillColor="blue"
                    iconStyle={{ borderColor: 'gray' }}
                />
                <Text>{text}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out. Apparently React native allows you to create refs to other components and you can use the reference.onPress() to activate the animation.